# Deleting unnecessary characters from pandas DataFrame entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x (xyz)', 'y [abc]'],['a (xyz)', 'b [bca]'],['xa (zyx)', 'yb [cab]']])
```

I want the following output:

```
    0   1
0   x   y
1   a   b
2   xa  yb
```

Currently, I'm doing it using the following code:

```
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].str.replace(r'\(.*\)','')
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].str.replace(r'\[.*\]','')
```

Is there a way to simplify it? Since in every cell, I'm trying to delete all characters after `(` or `[`, is there a way to maybe use `.join` and write this in one line? I'm just asking because if I have 100 columns where I need to do a similar cleaning, the way I'm doing now will become quite tedious.

Edit: I just realized,

```
df.iloc[:,0]=df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x[:x.find(' (')])
df.iloc[:,1]=df.iloc[:,1].apply(lambda x: x[:x.find(' [')])
```

will work too. However, I also don't know how to write a single `apply` function. Is there a way to combine these two lines of code too?

Comment: Depending on the original dataset `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[0])` could also work

Comment: @ScootCork In my original data, I have cases where I need to keep two words, so that won't quite work. But of course it works on this specific example. However, your solution got me thinking about another way. I edited my question to ask about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
df.replace(r'\s\(.*\)|\s\[.*\]','', regex=True)

    0   1
0   x   y
1   a   b
2  xa  yb
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. However, it seems `df.replace(r'\(.*\)|\[.*\]','', regex=True)` works as well. What is the role of `\s` here? (I'm just confused because in this specific example, it works without it)

Comment: ``\s`` Matches any space, tab or newline character.

Comment: @Sushanth so does it mean that if there is no `\s`, the space before the brackets is kept?

Comment: @NewbieAF exactly